# Open source tool for FMI/FMU in Excel?

Tags: excel, modelica, fmi

I am looking for an open-source tool for using FMU/FMI in Excel, but there are only two commercial tools after a dig on the internet, so my question is if there is an open-source tool for FMI/FMU in Excel?

Here are the links to available commercial tools:
https://www.claytex.com/products/fmi-blockset/#1499031584634-8ef448c3-9ff7
https://www.modelon.com/now-available-fmi-add-in-for-excel-v2-0/
http://www.xrg-simulation.de/en/products/applications/score

Comment: For the sake of completeness: There also is Score commercially available at http://www.xrg-simulation.de/en/products/applications/score, but I do not know why it is not listed at https://fmi-standard.org/tools/.

Comment: Why has this question been closed? I don't see how it conflicts with any Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: I don't understand it either, especially as it is about Functional Mockup Interface (which even has a tag on here with > 100 questions [fmi]) and has been tagged correctly. I voted to reopen, let's wait and see.

Comment: The Closed notification I see is not terribly clear, but I think it was regarded as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is nothing.

The official fmi website lists a lot of tools at https://fmi-standard.org/tools/, but there is no open source tool for excel in that list.

Answer (score 2):

In LibreOffice you can use/call Python scripts, and there are two open source python fmi tools, so you might get something to work (I never tried). If you are able to run some basic example, it would be great to share that somewhere!

https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/sbasic/python/main0000.html